# Почему форма - черный квадрат?

Tags: windows, библиотеки, visual-studio

Вот смотрите я вчера скачал библиотеку для Visual Studio... [эту библиотеку](http://rghost.ru/34028761) , и у меня в итоге должно было получится вот это [видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QflKRRlcAs), там форма стала прозрачной, а у меня просто этот черный квадрат. Что делать?

Comment: что за библиотека? дайте название, а не ссылку на скачивание

Comment: ExtendAero.dll , я её по видео нашел, эта библиотека позволяет делать формы "Стеклянного" стиля.

Comment: название вопроса доставляет :D

Answer (score 1):

В свойствах контрола выбрать Dock -> Fill (вся форма станет прозрачной).
В системе Aero точно включен?

Comment: Да я так и делал, но у меня просто черный квадрат, форма не становится прозрачной. Да точно включен.